# C - SDL Inconsistent framerate and screen garbage fixed by call to printf?y

Tags: c, linux, sdl, frame-rate

I've been working on a very simple SDL strobe light program which flashes two different colors on the screen at a variable rate. The rate and the two colors are specified on the command line,
 ie: `./strobe 13 0xffffff 0x000000`. specifies a 13hz strobe rate, and white and black as color1 and color2 respectively. ./strobe -h displays the usage info and some other information. I compiled on Lubuntu 14.10 using gcc like this: 
`gcc strobe.c $(sdl-config --cflags --libs) -lSDL -std=c99 -pedantic -o strobe`

I used a "delta time" technique to limit the framerate to the specified value by computing the time required to render the frame at the end of the loop, and calling `SDL_Delay()` if the frame finished "early".

The only problem I really have is that the frame rate seemed a bit jerky and inconsistent, and I noticed some garbage in the upper right hand corner of the screen (upper right hand corner of the window when not in fullscreen). The duty cycle between the two colors seemed to vary slightly as well sometimes and I could find no reason for this looking at the code.

Perhaps the most puzzling part (to me) was this: I added a call to `printf()` right before the call to `SDL_Delay()` in order to print the value of `t` (number of milliseconds spent on that frame), to see if it varied wildly. Much to my surprise, this simple thing fixed the problem, no more garbage in the top corner of the screen, and the framerate seemed much more consistent! The only problem is that I cannot figure out how in the world this makes any difference, and I do not want to fill the terminal with the current value of `t` on every frame. I am asking this question here in the hopes that someone more knowledgeable of SDL than I (i am just getting acquainted with SDL myself) can elucidate this, and provide some insight as to the mechanism of this strange anomaly in my code.

I will post the code below, in it's entirety. Forgive me if I should have omitted the more irrelevant bits, i was tempted to do so but feel that it may be better to provide a complete picture.

The last few lines at the end of the outer while loop in main is where i *think* the problem may be.

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define HRES 640
#define VRES 480
#define NCOLORS 2
#define MAXFPS 400

Uint16 create_hicolor_pixel(SDL_PixelFormat * fmt, Uint8 red, Uint8 green,
              Uint8 blue)
{
    Uint16 value;
    /* This series of bit shifts uses the information from the SDL_Format
     * structure to correctly compose a 16-bit pixel value from 8-bit RGB */
    value = ((red  >> fmt->Rloss) << fmt->Rshift) +
        ((green >> fmt->Gloss) << fmt->Gshift)    +
        ((blue  >> fmt->Bloss) << fmt->Bshift);

    return value;
}

int getargs(int argc, char **argv, int *fps, Uint32 *rgb_color)
{
    int error = 0;
    /* Command line args */
    if (argc < 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Too few parameters.\n");
        error = 1;
    } else if (argc > 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Too many parameters.\n");
        error = 1;
    } else {
        char *endptr;

        *fps = (int) strtol(*++argv, &endptr, 0);
        if (endptr == *(argv - 1) || (*fps < 1 || *fps > MAXFPS)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Bad frequency value. Try values between 1 - %d\n",
                    MAXFPS);
            error = 1;
        }

        rgb_color[0] = (Uint32) strtol(*++argv, &endptr, 16);
        if ((endptr == *(argv - 1)) || (rgb_color[0] < 0) || 
                                     (rgb_color[0] > 0xffffff)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Bad color value. Must be valid 24bit RGB hex\n");
            error = 1;
        }

        rgb_color[1] = (Uint32) strtol(*++argv, &endptr, 16);
        if ((endptr == *(argv - 1)) || (rgb_color[1] < 0) || 
                                     (rgb_color[1] > 0xffffff)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Bad color value. Must be valid 24bit RGB hex\n");
            error = 1;
        }
    }

    return error;
}

void showusageinfo(char *prgname)
{
    printf("\nUsage: %s [freq] [color1] [color2]\n\n", prgname);

    printf("Strobe is a simple program that uses the users monitor to implement a\n"
        "strobe light effect. The user can set the flash frequency and the two\n"
        "colors to flash between by passing these to strobe as command line\n"
        "arguments. Strobe uses the SDL library, and currently displays in\n"
        "hi-color (16bit) mode. User entered color values are automatically\n"
        "composed into the correct hi-color format for the user's system.\n\n");

    printf("The first parameter is the strobe rate (frequency) in hertz or cycles\n"
        "per second. This parameter takes a decimal value from 1 to MAXFPS.\n"
        "Flash rates higher than your monitors refresh rate will probably not\n"
        "display correctly. You may also be limited by the speed of your machine's"
        "\n\nCPU and video card.\n");

    printf("The second two parameters shall be 24bit RGB hexadecimal values for\n"
        "color1 and color2 respectively such as 0xffffff for white, and\n"
        "0xffff00 for yellow. As of version 0.1 common names of colors are\n"
        "not supported.\n\n");

    printf("An example for running strobe at a 15hz strobe rate, with yellow and\n"
        "a turquois shade of blue as color1 and color2, respectively:\n\n"
        "strobe 15 0xffff00 0x0080ff\n\n");

    printf("Pressing the 'ESC' key, or the 'q' key while strobe is running will\n"
           "safely exit from the program.\n\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SDL_Surface *screen;
    SDL_Event   event;
    Uint16  *scr_pixels;
    Uint16  hicolor_color[NCOLORS];
    Uint32  rgb_color[NCOLORS];
    int     coloridx = 0;
    int x, y, i;
    int quit = 0;
    int fps, t;

    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "-h") == 0) {
        showusageinfo(*argv);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    if (getargs(argc, argv, &fps, rgb_color) != 0) {
        printf("Usage: %s [freq] [color1] [color2]\n"
               "       %s -h to see help info for this program.\n\n",
               *argv, *argv);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Init SDL */
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    atexit(SDL_Quit);

    (void) SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Strobe", "Strobe");

    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(HRES, VRES, 16, SDL_HWSURFACE  |
                                              SDL_DOUBLEBUF  |
                                              0 );//no fullscreen until fixed
    if (screen == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to set video mode: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*Initialize hicolor colors*/
    for (i = 0; i < NCOLORS; ++i) {
        hicolor_color[i] = create_hicolor_pixel(screen->format,
                                                (rgb_color[i] & 0xff0000) >> 16,
                                                (rgb_color[i] & 0xff00)   >> 8,
                                                (rgb_color[i] & 0xff)     >> 0);
    }

    /* Get a pointer to the video surface's memory. */
    scr_pixels = (Uint16*) screen->pixels;

    while (!quit) {
        t = SDL_GetTicks();
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    quit = 1;
                    break;
                case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                    switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
                        case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                        case SDLK_q:
                            quit = 1;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        SDL_LockSurface(screen);
        coloridx ^= 1;
        for(x = 0; x < HRES; x++) {
            for(y = 0; y < VRES; y++) {
                scr_pixels[(screen->pitch >> 1) * y + x] = hicolor_color[coloridx];
            }
        }
        SDL_UnlockSurface(screen);
        SDL_Flip(screen);

        assert(SDL_GetTicks() > t);
        if ((t = SDL_GetTicks() - t) < 1000 / fps) {
            printf("%d\n", t); //why does this fix the framerate problem?
            SDL_Delay((1000 / fps) - t);
        }
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

for some reason that `printf()` call before the call to `SDL_Delay()` fixes the garbage ... but even more perplexing to me is the fact that when I tried replacing it with `putchar('\0')` the problem appears again so for some reason, only a call to `printf()` fixes it, and not `putchar()` which leads me to wonder what other calls might have this same effect, and what mechanism this effect may be caused by.

Comment: i'd like to also add that I just tried redirecting stdout to /dev/null so that nothing would appear in the terminal and the same screen garbage occured, but letting it go to the terminal fixes it??

Comment: Does full screen mode help?

Comment: it gives the same behavior in fullscreen. i also tried 32bpp instead of hicolor, as well as a few different resolutions with the same results (garbage on the screen and jerky framerate). the said call to `printf()` seems to remedy or at least hide the problem in fullscreen as well. it's interesting to me that redirecting stdout to /dev/null causes the problem to return (even with the call to `printf()`.)

Comment: Printf is probably changing the timing. Can you try on a different computer?

Comment: i added a command line option to toggle `printf()` statements sending the frame execution time to stderr. I tried this on another machine running lubuntu, except this machine runs the default open source video drivers. apart from the expected "regular" page tearing the behavior was correct. im starting to suspect this could be an issue with the AMD catalyst drivers, as when turning off the "tear free" mode i get the correct behavior (but w/ tearing). the "garbage" looks like small blocks of pixels from the prev/next frame. The AMD catalyst drivers definitely have a few quirks it seems.

Comment: So it's a driver issue? Frustrating, but good to know.

Comment: yep. turning off tear free mode fixed it.

Comment: Can you turn your findings into an answer, for posterity?

Answer (score 0):

I started suspecting the AMD Catalyst drivers (Omega 14.12) so after adding a command line option to print the current frame number, frame execution time, and average framerate, I tried the program on another machine running Lubuntu using the default open source drivers. On this machine, everything worked as it should be expected.

Disabling the "tear free" option in Catalyst Control Center, fixed the screen corruption. Based on the results i've seen I believe that this issue may be originating from a lower level, probably involving the AMD video drivers.